# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Record Too Large

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have an application that is trying to send fairly large (>4 mb) messages over Kafka via Spring Cloud Stream. I'm currently getting this error:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: This emssage is 4280852 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration

Is there a way to set "max.request.size" for a Spring Cloud Stream producer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a known issue and should be fixed as soon as https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/pull/588 is merged.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! We'll definitely be looking forward to 1.0.3 then!